# Does onbeforeunload works, if system crashes or shutdown forcefully by user?

Tags: javascript

It is working fine, when closing browser tab or window, but i am not able to test the scenario, if PC crashes or user shutdown the PC forcefully. I have searched a lot, but not able to find answer, Can someone help?

Comment: Not for sure. A crash may not invoke this event. How should it work? A shutdown could send a close command to the browser and the event is called. But maybe you have no more time to handle it. It's not a good idea to use this.

Answer (score 2):

No, it won't fire under those circumstances.

You should never build a system that *depends* on the client explicitly informing the server that it is being closed down.